# Multiple Monitors RDP VM in Cloud

Tags: virtual-machine, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, cloud

Currently, I am using 3 monitors on my desktop PC as I run a software with many windows and I save and restore the layouts(work space) of these widows.

I am planning to move to the could and was wondering how this would work in the cloud world. What I am not quite clear about

1. Can I configure the cloud VM to have 3 monitors just like the way I have it locally.
2. Or am I thinking about this wrong, you can't choose how many monitors yuou have on the cloud.  I will just expand the RDP window across my monitors and then just work with it.

Please provide any insights as to how is it generally done in a multiple monitor setup.